# uglifyjs a javascript class - unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6, uglifyjs2

I'm trying to write some new javascript using classes and I'm getting an "'Unexpected token: name (Utils)'" error when trying to minify the piece of code with uglifyjs2.

Here is my class

```
'use strict';

class Utils {
    // Constructor
    constructor() {
        marvin.Utils = Utils;
    }

    // Build a Form
    buildForm(keys) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
        var form = {};
        keys.forEach(function(index,key) {
            form[key] = args[index];
        });
        return form;
    }

    // Unique values
    unique(data) {
        return new Set(data);
    }
}
```

When trying to minify with uglifyjs, I get the following error

'Unexpected token: name (Utils)',

which corresponds to the **U** in the first line, "class Utils {".

I know there seem to be some issues with uglifyjs2 minifying the new ES6 standards but I don't know if that's the problem, or just some syntax thing I'm missing.  I've tried uglifyjs2 and grunt-contrib-uglify and I get the same error.

If it is an ES6 problem, does anyone know of a solution available on how to properly minify the new JS class?  I've tried using Babel (grunt-babel) in my grunt to transpile my code from ES6 to ES5, but that didn't actually change the code structure at all.  What is the equivalent form of a class in ES5?  This is my post-transpiled code.

**Update**

Ok.  So I didn't have the correct Babel presets and plugins installed and loaded in my Gruntfile.  So I installed them, but it's still not working. During Babel runtime, I'm getting the error

Running "babel" task

```
Running "babel:dist" (babel) task
Verifying property babel.dist exists in config...OK
Files: js/es6/utils.js -> js/es6/utils.new.js
Options: sourceRoot="etc/", sourceMap=false, presets=["babel-preset-es2015"], plugins=["babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes"]
Warning: Unknown plugin "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "js/es6" Use --force to continue.
```

Here is my Gruntfile config.  I have my node_modules and gruntfile somewhere else than where my application source files are.

```
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    // Babel - transpiler from ES6 to ES5
    babel: {
        options: {
            sourceRoot: 'etc/',
            sourceMap: false,
            presets: ['babel-preset-es2015'],
            plugins: ["babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes"]
        },
        dist: {
          files: [{
            expand: true,
            src: ['js/es6/*.js'],
            ext: '.new.js'
          }]
        }
    }
  });
// Set default file path
  grunt.file.setBase('../python/marvin/web/static/');
```

My application tree looks like this, and I'm running grunt inside the etc/ directory. All my javascript files are inside the js subdirectory many levels down.

- trunk/

  - etc/

    - node_modules/
    - Gruntfile.js
    - package.json
  - python/

    - marvin/

      - web/

        - static/

          - js/

            - es6/

              - utils.js
          - css/

How can I tell the babel config that my presets/plugins are in one directory, but my javascript files are in another?

Comment: The problem is definitely with Uglify's missing support for ES6 classes. I've put your code into the online Babel compiler, and it looks very different after compilation. Maybe you didn't set the correct transpiler presets? Here's the link if you want to try yourself: https://babeljs.io/repl/

Comment: Yeah it seems I was missing some grunt-babel plugins and presets for transpiling to es2015.  I've added them in, but now I'm getting an error where grunt-babel can't find the plugins/presets relative the directory where my files are located.  I've updated the main text above with more information

Comment: Try `presets: ['es2015']` and `plugins: ["transform-es2015-classes"]` although I'm not sure why you even need the plugin.

Comment: Maybe I don't with the presets.  At any rate, I get the same 'unknown plugin' error.  If I remove the plugin altogether, I get the error "Warning: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "js/es6" Use --force to continue." with the preset.  I can see the plugins in my etc/ directory.  Somehow Babel thinks the main directory is js/es6/, and paths are all messed up.

Comment: did you `npm install babel-preset-es2015 --save-dev`?

Comment: Yeah I did.  In my devDependencies, I have "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I solved it by restructuring my directory system to be more in line with the other examples I've seen.  Basically with my Gruntfile, package.json, and node_modules in the same directory level as my source files.  Here is my new structure...

- trunk/

  - etc/
  - python/

    - marvin/

      - web/

        - static/

          - js/
          - css/
          - src/
          - Gruntfile.js
          - package.json
          - node_modules/

and my new Babel config in my Gruntfile file looks like

```
babel: {
    options: {
        sourceMap: false,
        presets: ['es2015']
    },
    dist: {
      files: [{
        expand: true,
        cwd: 'src',
        src: ['**/*.js'],
        dest: 'js',
        ext: '.js'
      }]
    }
}
```

Everything transpiles correctly now, and I can properly minify with uglifyjs.